# How to get local ip in Ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ip-address

i have a problem with ionic 2 and cordova plugin network interface, i already install the plugin and in home.ts i declared a variable with the same name, type any, for get ip address, i see the tutorial of that plugin in github, but in my app doesn't works, can you help me?

home.ts:

```
declare var networkinterface:any;
@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html',
providers: [NodeProvider]
})
export class HomePage {
 public ip = "";

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public loadCtrl:   LoadingController, public nodeProvider: NodeProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

ionViewDidLoad(){
networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) {
    console.log((ip));
});
```

}

And errors ionic throws me:

[image: Ionic error]

Comment: you seem to be trying this in browser. It works in android and ios only as the docs says. try it in real device.